# ImageJ plugins with dependencies or uberjar assembly are not available in FiJi plugins

Tags: java, plugins, dependencies, imagej, fiji

I am writing an ImageJ/FiJi plugin. when I build my project with the following `pom.xml` and `uberjar.xml`, I get the following jar files;

```
MyFirstPlg-0.1.0.jar
MyFirstPlg-0.1.0-sources.jar
MyFirstPlg-0.1.0-uberjar.jar
MyFirstPlg-0.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

If I copy/paste each jar file at a time into plugins in FiJi and check if I can see my plugin in the plugins after restarting FiJi;

**MyFirstPlg-0.1.0.jar** and **MyFirstPlg-0.1.0-uberjar.jar**: I can see my plugin but the dependency are missing, so it raises error for dependency, e.g. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tensorflow/ndarray/NdArray`. Although, based on the size **MyFirstPlg-0.1.0-uberjar.jar** is the largest and I think it has all dependencies.

**MyFirstPlg-0.1.0-sources.jar** and **MyFirstPlg-0.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar**: I do not see my plugin in the plugins.

I wonder what I am missing in my pom.xml and uberjar.xml files that causes this problem. I have checked in Maven webpage for assembly [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-components.html) but could not find what I am missing.

BTW; if I run my plugin as Java Application in eclipse it does not raise any error and works as expected.

Here are the main parts of the `pom.xml` file. I curated defaults required parts; e.g., mailings, scm, license, contributors, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <!-- scijava is required and put in parent, I donot know why! -->
    <!-- but is required for; org.scijava.* -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.scijava</groupId>
        <artifactId>pom-scijava</artifactId>
        <version>26.0.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
        
    <!-- this is my project information -->
    <groupId>org.mic.imageseg</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyFirstPlg</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    
    <!-- here mailing list, contributers, license, scm, etc, defaults required -->
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scijava.public</id>
            <url>https://maven.scijava.org/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    
    <build>
    <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/models</directory> <!-- I have some tensorflow model to be included in the jar file -->
     </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase> 
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <descriptors> 
              <descriptor>src/assembly/uberjar.xml</descriptor>  <!-- this where my uberjar.xml file located.-->
            </descriptors>
        <includes>
            <include>
                <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
                <artifactId>imagej</artifactId>
            </include>
            <include>
                <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>tensorflow-core-platform</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.1</version>
            </include>
        </includes>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <!-- here goes dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
            <artifactId>imagej</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>tensorflow-core-platform</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

and this is my `uberjar.xml`which is located in `src/assembly`folder.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
    <id>uberjar</id>
      <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
      </formats>
      <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
      <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        </dependencySet>
      </dependencySets>
      <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
          <outputDirectory>\</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
      </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I took the time to read what you describe. You're mentioning that Eclipse doesn't throw errors for the plug in as Java application. I think it's the way you reference the plug in  your pom.xml. Fortunately I don't have to deal with that nonsense for now and hopefully never! lol. Try asking the question on javaranch too

Comment: Thanks, I will ask on javaranch as well.