# File search in python

Tags: python

I need a file in a dir by it's name

I achieved this with

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("../path")

def search_file(file_to_search):
    for file in glob.glob(file_to_search):
        return file
```

in another function I am using

```
with open("./file.csv",'rt')as f:
        lines = list(csv.reader(f))
        for line in lines:
            var = line[1]
            path = search_file(var)
```

Before I add the search_file function in the second process the file.csv is found.
After it is not found anymore. I assume it has to do with the **os** import?

a work around was this

```
def find_file(file):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./path'):
        if file in files:
            return os.path.join(root, file)
```

Does anyone has a solid explanation why with open() would clash with os, if that is the case?

note: the indentation might be wrong, assume the code is running, I got it from functions

**Update:**

I feel I need to give some more clarity:

This is what I achieve so far with what I have:

1. Function1 to read a cell from a csv file and if the name in the cell matches the name of a file in a directory, return fill path
2. Function2 to take parameter(Function1 return ) give the path to json.load(), give the load to json.dump, assign it to key(that expects json format)
3. Function processes.

This might make more sense.

Comment: "file,csv" is not qualified. Is it in whatever folder you're switching to with the os.chdir("../path") statement? I suggest you use absolute file names, not unqualified names which depend on the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected that. in my code was using absolute path. i think i missed it here

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code as below:

file.csv has 2 lines as below;
file1,file1.txt
file2,file2.txt

I have two txt files in path; file1.txt, file2.txt

and I tried your code it worked.

Except in your original code you have `for file in glob.glob(file_file_to_search):` changed to `for file in glob.glob(file_to_search):`

```
import glob, os
    os.chdir("../path")
    
def search_file(file_to_search):
    for file in glob.glob(file_to_search):
        return file

with open("file.csv",'rt')as f:
        lines = list(csv.reader(f))
        for line in lines:
            var = line[1]
            path = search_file(var)
            print(path)
```

Here is the ouput:

```
>>> with open("file.csv",'rt')as f:
...         lines = list(csv.reader(f))
...         for line in lines:
...             var = line[1]
...             path = search_file(var)
...             print(path)
...
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Let`s say you have file.csv in your main folder and your path on Desktop.
Still your code works.

```
import glob, os

file_to_search = "Desktop/path"

def search_file(file_to_search):
    for file in glob.glob(file_to_search):
        return file

with open("file.csv",'rt')as f:
        lines = list(csv.reader(f))
        for line in lines:
            var = line[1]
            var = file_to_search + "/" + var
            path = search_file(var)
            print(path)
```

Here is code on terminal:

```
>>> import glob, os
>>>
>>> file_to_search = "Desktop/path"
>>>
>>> def search_file(file_to_search):
...     for file in glob.glob(file_to_search):
...             return file
...
>>> with open("file.csv",'rt')as f:
...             lines = list(csv.reader(f))
...             for line in lines:
...                     var = line[1]
...                     var = file_to_search + "/" + var
...                     path = search_file(var)
...                     print(path)
...
Desktop/path/file1.txt
Desktop/path/file2.txt
```

Comment: thank you, it was a typing mistake, changing vars for stack overflow.

Comment: just a question, why should i do it your way when my way is shorter?

Comment: There are several solutions, I suggested the one easier for me. As you know your path, `glob.glob` works as I suggested. `os.walk` can be used as well. I generally use it if I do not know dirs and folders in the path. At the end, it does not make difference as long as either way works.

Comment: this is the way. python people. lol. you'd never hear that from a java developer. nice one cosacak. thanks for sharing. I am sure one day i'll come back here

Comment: I have same struggle in Java :))) I am asking a lot of simple questions on GitHub or OS. Please find one of them here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66976317/imagej-plugins-with-dependencies-or-uberjar-assembly-are-not-available-in-fiji-p

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should search for a file, and open it if it is found.

```py
import os
path = os.listdir('./')
newfile = input('Enter the file name: ')
for found in path:
    if str(found) == newfile:
        print(f'{str(found)} matches your search.')
        os.system(f'open {found}')
        break
    else:
        print(f'{str(found)} does not match your search.')
```

Comment: what if i would need the root to join the file name when I return it. Say root = ./hello ; fileName = hello1.csv. I need it returned ./hello/hello1.csv

I essence what I try to achieve is getting and i have achieve with my code is to: 1. take file name from json, 2.search for that filename in a directory; 3. if the filename is found in that directory return the full pat; 4. pass the return to a json.dump. I am doing all this because I have data that might change and it's easier to keep it separate for the long run, plus ther's only one function processing, instead a function for each json.

Answer (score 0):

if you want get the full path of a file in a folder;

```
files = glob.glob("./hello/*")
```

or search for a pattern; e.g., files ending with csv.

```
files = glob.glob("./hello/*.csv")
```

First check if your file is in the list and find the index of the file you are searching for [you can get help from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779526/finding-a-substring-within-a-list-in-python) and if it is in the list.

```
the_file = files[the_index_of_the_file]
```

the_file has the full path.

```
the_file.split("/")[-1] #will give you the file name.
```